# unable to delete object from coredata entity swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

it is deleting data from core data but on `deleteRowsAtIndexpaths` it gives error which is ['Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (5) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (5), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).']

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete)
        {
            var Id = String()
                if let RowData : NSDictionary = self.SavedJobs[indexPath.row] as? NSDictionary{
                   Id = RowData["vacancy_id"] as! String

                }


            let OptionMenu = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Vacancy has been deleted", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            let Okay = UIAlertAction(title: "Okay" , style: .Cancel, handler: {
                (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
                let appDelegate =
                    UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

                let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
                print("saved data pre is \(self.SavedData)")
                let Job = self.SavedData[indexPath.row] as NSManagedObject
                managedContext.deleteObject(Job)
                if (self.SavedData[indexPath.row].deleted){  
                do{
                    try managedContext.save()
                }
                catch{}
                }
                self.SavedJobs.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
                self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
                self.DeleteService(Id)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
            OptionMenu.addAction(Okay)
            self.presentViewController(OptionMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show your `numberOfRowsInSection` method, but my guess is that your are using SavedData as your datasource, but the above code removes the deleted object from SavedJobs.

Comment: func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return SavedData.count
    }

Comment: i am also removing coredata object ?
managedContext.deleteObject(Job) by this command

Comment: Yes - deleteObject marks the object as deleted, but you still have a reference to it in `SavedData`.  Try changing `self.SavedJobs.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row)` to `self.SavedData.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row)`.

Comment: yes it worked, thanks buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using beginUpdates and endUpdates? i.e

```
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.SavedJobs.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
        self.DeleteService(Id)
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

Also, you dont need to call `self.tableview.reloadData()` when using `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths`

Comment: ... and you don't need `beginUpdates / endUpdates` for a single delete operation.